# Unable to create TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, soap-api, ssjs

I am unable to create TriggerSendDefinition using SOAP API call in POSTMAN. I am following the [official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_triggered_send_definition.htm) to create the TriggersendDefination. Not sure where I am doing wrong. Please find the below request code.

```xml
      <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            <CustomerKey>Ranjan_oBill_Cancellation</CustomerKey>
            <Name>Ranjan_oBill_Cancellation</Name>
            <SendClassification>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey>Default Transactional</CustomerKey>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            </SendClassification>
            <Email>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ID>2506</ID>
            </Email>
            <SendSourceDataExtension>
               <CustomerKey>075E6EC1-D9A2-40AB-BDAF-54D767FDE1F6</CustomerKey>
            </SendSourceDataExtension>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>`
```

I am receiving the Error code stating that:

> **Exception occurred during [CreateTriggeredSendDefinition] ErrorID: 526703216**

Could someone help me on this regard. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can raise a support ticket and give the error ID (in your case its - 526703216) to them then they can specify whats the error from their logs.

However you can use the below steps for troubleshoot to resolve the error by yourself:

- You need to have a valid email
- You would need to provide the email ID not the asset ID
- Triggered send data extension should have been created
- Send Classification external key should be provided

Below code works for me in my instance:

Try it by adding the MID and providing the customer key for email.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Options/>
         <Objects xsi:type="TriggeredSendDefinition">
            <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Client>
                    <ClientID>MID</ClientID>
                </Client>Client>
            <CustomerKey>Ranjan_oBill_Cancellation</CustomerKey>
            <Name>Ranjan_oBill_Cancellation</Name>
            <SendClassification>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <CustomerKey>Default Transactional</CustomerKey>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
            </SendClassification>
            <Email>
               <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
               <ID>2506</ID>
               <CustomerKey>**Email customer key**</CustomerKey>
            </Email>
            <SendSourceDataExtension>
               <CustomerKey>075E6EC1-D9A2-40AB-BDAF-54D767FDE1F6</CustomerKey>
            </SendSourceDataExtension>
         </Objects>
      </CreateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Thank you @Naveen, this works for me.

Comment: You are welcome @Ranjan!